# Debugging Laravel API test

Tags: laravel, testing, laravel-artisan

When running `php artisan test` in a Laravel API, nothing is returned. No errors or responses. I have a pretty simple API with on the `api.php` route file:

```php
Route::group(['prefix' => '{facultyId}'], function () {
    Route::resource('awards', AwardController::class);
});
```

A Feature test that tests the endpoint returns a `200` and the model exists.

```php
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;
use Tests\TestCase;

class TestInfoTest extends TestCase
{
    use WithoutMiddleware;

    /** @test */
    public function test_get_endpoint_exists()
    {
        $response = $this->getJson(route('test.index', [
            'facultyId' => '0000001', 
            'page' => 1, 
            'itemsPerPage' => 5, 
            'search' => ''
        ]));
        
        $response
            ->assertStatus(200)
            ->assertJson([
                'message' => 'Success'
            ]);    
    }

    /** @test */
    public function test_is_there_a_model()
    {
        $test = Test::find(1);

        return $this->assertModelExists($test);
    }
}
```

If I only run one method, it passes for both methods, but if I run the whole test class, nothing is returned, no failures or passes. I have tried `$respons->dump()`, and the getJson request returns successfully with a 200 and a message 'Success.'  I have been pulling my hair out, trying to figure this out.  I have also added:
`ini_set('display_errors',1); error_reporting(-1);` to artisan.php. Also, here is my phpunit.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="https://schema.phpunit.de/9.3/phpunit.xsd" bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php" colors="true">
  <coverage processUncoveredFiles="true">
    <include>
      <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>
    </include>
  </coverage>
  <testsuites>
    <testsuite name="Unit">
      <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Unit</directory>
    </testsuite>
    <testsuite name="Feature">
      <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Feature</directory>
    </testsuite>
  </testsuites>
  <php>
    <server name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
    <server name="BCRYPT_ROUNDS" value="4"/>
    <server name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
     <server name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/>
     <server name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/>
    <server name="MAIL_MAILER" value="array"/>
    <server name="QUEUE_CONNECTION" value="sync"/>
    <server name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    <server name="TELESCOPE_ENABLED" value="false"/>
  </php>
</phpunit>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I have tried many different things to try and solve the issue, such as:

- `php artisan test tests/Feature/MyFeatureTest.php`
- `php artisan cache:clear`
- `php artisan config:clear`
- `php artisan test --debug`
- `php artisan test --stop-on-failure`

I also need to add that I am using an Oracle database without migrations.

Comment: Just in case, replace `<server name ....>` with `<env name ...>` and tell me what happened

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `Tests\TestCase` file. You may use traits such as `refreshDatabase` or something else that affect your data while test passing through one method to another one.

Comment: Looks like my TestCase is the default laravel TestCase file with the  use CreatesApplication; And CreatesApplication is the same default file `public function createApplication()
    {
        $app = require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';

        $app->make(Kernel::class)->bootstrap();

        return $app;
    }`
I also need to add that I am using an Oracle database without migrations